# Application.cfm missing Session variables after 301 redirect

Tags: coldfusion, http-status-code-301, coldfusion-7, application.cfm

Running ColdFusion 7.

The Application.cfm loops all `session` variables into `request.session`

The OnRequestEnd.cfm loops all `request.session` values back into `session`

It does this so it only needs to lock the scope once when writing the variables in a single transaction. (I believe this isn't so much an issue anymore? Yet I can't exactly rip it out).

I have a 'redirect.cfm' page which either provides a 301 redirect to an SEO URL or delivers the content.  Some forms post to the old URL, so need a 301 redirect which causes the loss of POST data. This is how I intended to handle it.

```
<!--- if form scope exists (posted data) copy it to the request.session scope ---> 
<cfif structKeyExists(form,'fieldNames')>
    <cfset request.session.postData = structCopy(form)>
</cfif>
```

Then it moves on to a 301 redirect, and when it comes back to redirect.cfm to deliver the content it runs this code

```
<!--- if request.session.postData exists (posted data) copy it to the form scope --->
<cfif structKeyExists(request.session,'postData')>
    <cfset form = structCopy(request.session.postData)>
    <cfset StructDelete(request.session,'postData')>
</cfif>
```

This works fine if a 301 redirect is not needed from post of data.

With a 301 redirect, I have confirmed the Application.cfm, OnRequestEnd.cfm both run twice (once for the initial 301 and once for the content delivery).

By the end of the first OnRequestEnd.cfm call `session.postdata` is populated correctly with the form data.

After the 301 redirect and it hits Application.cfm again the `session.postdata` returns 'struct[empty]'

Any help? Thanks

Comment: I tested another idea, I set request.session.test = form.searchField on a 301 redirect and it worked. It looks like the problem might be to do with storing a structure in a request.session variable and passing it.

Comment: A redirect is a new request so if you want your post data to exist in your next screen you need to add it to a persistent scope like session or pass it in the URL.

Comment: Hi Travis, if you see the code snippets in my post that is what I'm doing. I am copying the form to request.session before the 301 redirect, the onRequestEnd.cfm writes this to the Session scope.

Comment: have you tried placing it directly into the session scope without having to have it "looped in"?

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish by copying session variables to the request scope?  I can't think of anything useful.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk, I think it's legacy code he's working with.  Daniel, how does your in script convert the request.session to session.  You can save a structure to the session scope, so that shouldn't be the problem.  It sounds like your copying in and out of scopes is only handling simple values?

Comment: @Travis I think that's about right. I tested `<cfset session.postData = structCopy(form)>
 <cfset session.postDataSubmit = 1>` the simple 'postDataSubmit' survives in the Session, the structure does not. The loop code is like this `<cflock timeout="30" throwontimeout="Yes" type="EXCLUSIVE" scope="SESSION">
<cfloop collection="#request.session#" item="i">
<cfset  session[i] = request.session[i]>
</cfloop>
</cflock>`

Comment: @DanBracuk Travis is right, it's legacy code - it's heavily integrated and I could not easily remove it.

Comment: @Travis furthermore, when stored directly into the session scope OnRequestEnd.cfm should not touch it. I checked the value entering the Application.cfm and session.postdata shows struct [empty]. Maybe I need to use something other than `structCopy(form)`

Comment: Oh of course... structcopy copies nested structures by reference, so when the form structure no longer exists, neither does your postdata structure.

Comment: try duplicate instead of structcopy

Comment: @Travis thanks a lot, that worked, write a quick note as an 'Answer' if you like and I'll mark it as such. Leaving work now, will do it in the morning.

Comment: done. sorry I didn't see it sooner.  to many superfluous comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[structCopy()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00000635.htm) creates a shallow copy of the structure, meaning that nested structures are by reference only which is why your simple values persisted but your nested structures did not.  Once your form structure no longer contained data your postData structure began referencing an empty structure so your reference is also empty.

To do a "Deep Copy" of your structures use [duplicate()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00000635.htm)

See also [other structure functions](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00000635.htm)

[CF 9 documentation for deleting structures](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09f0b-7fdc.html)

Comment: Even if what Adam says is correct about structCopy(), duplicate has resolved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: any thoughts why this works `<cfset form.test = duplicate(request.session.postData)>` but when I do `<cfset form = duplicate(request.session.postData)>` the form scope remains empty. This code is ran just before I `<cfinclude>` the content. Same with structCopy() Thanks

Comment: I'm going with this until I find a better solution `<cfloop collection="#request.session.postData#" item="i"><cfset form[i] = request.session.postData[i]></cfloop>` I feel so dirty..

Comment: I'm sure it has something to do with form being a full scope and not just a structure, a reserved word type protection. you can say form.someName = request.session.postData just fine, but I believe CF has a fail safe to prevent using scopes as structure names. If I'm wrong someone will chime in but that's my best guess. if your landing page is already coded and looking at the form scope, I think you're on the right track. If you're coding the landing page, I see no value in moving your postData back into the form scope, just code to use the postData structure. Lots of bouncing around already.

Comment: thanks, I may have to stick to the loop. This is a blanket fix for all forms on the website. There are over 50,000 content pages (of course not all forms), but it's a pretty large site.

Comment: @Travis, you're dead right, and I'm sorry I disagreed with you here. I've done some more looking into this, which I have documented on my blog, should you be interested: http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/i-love-being-wrong.html

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE: this answer is *wrong*. I've only left it here as I've done some [interesting investigation into the situation](http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/i-love-being-wrong.html), which might be worth people reading]

What @Travis said was the problem - that "when the form structure no longer exists, neither does your postdata structure" - is absolutely not true. The reference to the form scope might have gone, but as long as there's *any* reference to the data (like `request.session.postData`) then the underlying object will *not* be removed.

The problem is likely to be that when you do your redirect, OnRequestEnd.cfm doesn't run for that request, so the variables in request.session never get copied into the session scope.  It all depends on how you're doing the redirect. I'd've assumed it'd have been with a `<cflocation>`, except you say you're using CFMX7 which can't do a 301 (which you're say you're doing): it can only do a 302.  Can you pls clarify how you're doing this redirect? Cheers.

Digression: you're adding quite a lot of overhead plus a bottleneck at either end of the request in continuing with all this legacy session-locking shenanigans. You really ought to put aside some time to pull it all out. This locking session-scope-locking carry-on hasn't been necessary since CF5. Also if your session scope contains structs, you're not mitigating the problem anyhow. This is, obviously, an aside; and nothing to do with your actual question. I just figured it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Application.cfm and OnRequestEnd.cfm both run twice, once for the 301 and once for the content. I am sure that OnRequestEnd.cfm ran. I even dumped the content of the session scope built by OnRequestEnd.cfm which contained the form data. Then I dumped the Session scope at the beginning of the following Application.cfm call - when using structCopy() the structure was empty.

Comment: I am using `<cfheader statuscode="301" statustext="Moved Permanently">
<cfheader name="Location" value="http://xxxx">` for the redirect and it seems to run fine in CF7. Whilst not ideal, it would be costly to refactor the website or preferable build it around a modern CMS - we do have a CDN which alleviates the strain on the server,

Comment: Yes, I misspoke, the object exists as Daniel indicated by saying struct[empty] so the struct is there or he would have gotten a not defined in request error. However the form scope is empty so the copy is empty. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09f0b-7fdc.html

Comment: did some testing that says contrary to your answer. Can you post your source(s)?  a.user.name = "Travis"; b = structCopy(a); c=a; structDelete(a,'user'); a.user.name = "Adam"; <!--- no longer changes b and c ---> b.user.name = "Mike" <--- changes B and C but not A --->  I suppose this suggests the original object exists but is no longer accessible by re-creating a structure with the same name as the originally deleted structure?